# Front-face in Android camera by default

Tags: android, android-camera

I am using this code:

```
                Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                File photo = new File("/sdcard/picture.png");
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                Uri.fromFile(photo));
                Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
                startActivity(intent);
```

I would like to use this intent with a pre-defined setting, like front facing by default every time I fire the camera. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the front Camera intent, use it in your code!
here is an good tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCamera/article.html

```
int CAMERA_FACING_FRONT
```

Read more here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html